# Finding the run hooks and run_fold hooks

Tags: ejabberd-hooks

The documentation https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/hooks/ says there are two types of hooks **run_hook**(whose return type is not used) and **run_fold**(whose return type is used in future hooks) hook.

As an example for the run_fold hook the **filter_packet** is shown. There are lots of other hooks listed, but how to find which of the hooks are **run_hook** and **run_fold** hook?